# Long lasting cookies in node

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js

If I understand correctly `Express session` saves only `session id` in `session cookie` and retrieves information based on that `id` from the data store.

when user closes the browser, that information is lost.  I won't temper session cookies if I use:

```
res.cookie();
```

**How can I  include regular cookies that are not lost?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to use the method `res.cookie(...);`, you won't override anything in the session. Unless you actually set a cookie with the same name as the session cookie's name. Don't do that and you'll be golden.